# server start up issue in tomcat 7

Tags: spring, tomcat

I have web app based on spring framework , while running the server I am getting the below error and it is **getting stuck , server is not starting.** Please help on this.

```
INFO: SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
```

Comment: That is not an error at all. It's an informative message. That's what `"INFO:"` means.

Comment: please post the full error message you receive, if it's a stacktrace can you post the full stacktrace with all the Caused By traces,if it's too big can you post a link to pastebin.com

Answer (score 0):

As JB Nizet mentioned, that's an informative message that Spring prints when it loads the sql error code mappings.

You can see the code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.jdbc/3.1.0/org/springframework/jdbc/support/SQLErrorCodesFactory.java). On line 126 you'll see the log message.